Spring cloud data flow cannot find driver class at startup
I'm trying to up spring cloud data flow in my local. By default SCDF use h2 as primary database to store meta information. In my cloud-task-batch application all the properties related to database are mentioned and  dependency are present but still SCDF is trying to find h2.
Dependency and property
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/batchtest
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.username=root

<dependency>
<groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
<artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
<version>8.4.0</version>
</dependency>

I found this solution to connect SCDF to mysql database.
'java -jar spring-cloud-dataflow-server-2.11.4.jar --spring.datasource.url='jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/batchtest' --spring.datasource.username=root --spring.datasource.password=root --spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver '
But while my trying to startup the SCDF getting this issue.
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:97)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.determineDriverClassName(DataSourceProperties.java:175)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder(DataSourceProperties.java:125)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration.createDataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:48)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.dataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:90)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)

I'm new in SCDF. Please help me

SCDF doesn't package the MySQL driver because of License restrictions by Oracle.
The documentation does describe how to configure the MariaDB driver org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver to correctly connect to MySQL Database.
